# How to use if and if-else statements inside of while loops

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

How should I use `if` and `else` statements inside of `while` loops in C++? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I think it might have something to do with the `float` variables, or maybe it's where the code is after the `while` loop.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    float FEnemyPos[3] = { 15.1f, 30.1f, 50.1f };

    char cEnemyTypes[3][10] = { "Trolls", "skeletons", "Axemen" };

    float fPlayerPos = 20;
    float fPlayerMoves;

    float Ftrolldistance;
    float Fskeledistance;
    float Faxemendistance;
    float fValueEntered = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter number \t";
    while (fValueEntered != -99) {
        std::cout << "Please enter number \t";
        std::cin >> fPlayerMoves;

        fValueEntered = fValueEntered + fPlayerMoves;

        fPlayerPos = fPlayerMoves + fPlayerPos;//player position

        std::cout << "value entered" << fValueEntered;
        std::cout << "player pos" << fPlayerPos;

        Ftrolldistance = FEnemyPos[1] - fPlayerPos;
        Fskeledistance = FEnemyPos[2] - fPlayerPos;
        Faxemendistance = FEnemyPos[3] - fPlayerPos;

        std::cout << "troll distance " << Ftrolldistance;


        if (Ftrolldistance <= 2 && Ftrolldistance >= -2) //if troll is less <2 and more then -2,
        {
            std::cout << "trolls are close";//print you are in danger
        }

        else if (Fskeledistance <= 2 && Fskeledistance >= -2)//if skelle is less <2 and more then - 2,
        {
            std::cout << "skelle are close ";//print you are in danger
        }

        else if (Faxemandistance <= 2 && Faxemendistance >= -2)//if axemen is less <2 and more then - 2,
        {
            std::cout << "axemen are close";//print you are in danger
        }


        else
        {
            std::cout << "you are safe for now \t";//else print you are safe
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much code, poorly explained problem (actually.. what _is_ the problem?), posted C++ code as an inline runnable HTML/JS snippet (wtf?)...

Comment: Oh, and don't use the "n word" on Stack Overflow. Or at all. Thanks.

Comment: sorry i didnt post it in the correct format still new at this, and its messy ive just been trying to get this thing working for ages, sorry about using the n word lol i forgot it wasnt in there but its clearly not used in a derogatorily term, its just apart of my vocab because i listen to alot of rap music, sorry if i offended anyone by it =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Poor** code quality, have you heard about **code style** ? **comments** ?
Have you runned the code ?
I'll give you a tip, after writing a piece of code, before compiling read it from the bottom up it will help you detect problems like this one :
**The first index of an array is always 0** !!!
so the **3rd value in the array has 2 as index**
=> so technically :

```
Faxemendistance = FEnemyPos[3] - fPlayerPos;
```

Will generate an error. To fix it, you have to write :

```
Ftrolldistance = FEnemyPos[0] - fPlayerPos;
Fskeledistance = FEnemyPos[1] - fPlayerPos;
Faxemendistance = FEnemyPos[2] - fPlayerPos;
```

Comment: too true i forgot about that =P and i will try reading threw it like that too it makes sense

Comment: Why are you **shouting**?

Comment: me ?? if its the other guy thats shouting trying to help me i dont care at least he is trying to help me unlike other people cough cough lightness races

Comment: I'm not shouting, it's the bold with that font that makes you think that i'm shouting at him lol ! I'm trying to help here not shouting on people and to be sincere, sometimes, people need that to learn too!

Comment: dont worry about her, as they say haters gonna hate. because thats about all there good for and picking out irrelevant things that dont help ;P haha,i dont think its very productive to worry about if someone is shouting,but lets not make it about her ,  thanks Abdelkafi for your help but its really appreciated

Comment: My name is Ahmed by the way :D

Comment: omg god its alive and working , i feel like ive created Frankenstein, thanks everyone

Comment: hey Ahmed Abdelkafi do you think there is any chance i could get you to help me with something else, Add me on facebook

Answer (score 1):

Too much code, but i found out one issue...
Your array is of 3 members.

`float FEnemyPos[3] = { 15.1f, 30.1f, 50.1f };` but you are using it from index 1 and going upto index 3.

```
Ftrolldistance = FEnemyPos[1] - fPlayerPos;
Fskeledistance = FEnemyPos[2] - fPlayerPos;
Faxemendistance = FEnemyPos[3] - fPlayerPos;
```

You should change it like below, because you don't have anything in you array on index 3, it is invalid memory access when you try to access it.

```
Ftrolldistance = FEnemyPos[0] - fPlayerPos;
Fskeledistance = FEnemyPos[1] - fPlayerPos;
Faxemendistance = FEnemyPos[2] - fPlayerPos;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could shorten the code a lot!

- you could use a string list instead of a char array
- you could use less variables
- the if/else could be shortened

also the main problem is that an index always starts with 0